# The assigned value is never used

Tags: java, netbeans

Pretty sure the warning means that I declared a variable that I never used elsewhere but I'm almost positive I am using this variable.

The line it highlights is:

```
return fitIndex = ++i;
```

Yet if I remove the `++i` my code behaves erroneously.

If I do this instead:

```
fitIndex = ++i;
return fitIndex;
```

It gives no warnings.

Is there some interaction here with the return statement I'm missing? Doesn't it increment `i` first, then assign it to `fitIndex`, and then returns the value?

It doesn't affect my code at all, but just curious.

Comment: If `fitIndex` is declared inside a method but is not set then yes, the compiler won't like it.

Comment: @Tom, I realised and deleted that sentence :)

Comment: Is `fitIndex` a local variable, or a class field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any purpose to `fitIndex` (you never access the value, since you return immediately). In other words, the compiler thinks

```
return fitIndex = ++i;
```

can be replaced by

```
return ++i;
```

**tl;dr** you can remove `fitIndex`.